# Panels layout with sidebar next to 3 pane grid

Tags: panels, theming

I'm using Panels 3.2 on a fresh install of Drupal 7. I want to create a custom layout that I can use and manage via Panels, and the flexible editor is great, but not quite sufficient for the layout I want (as far as I can tell).

Currently I have a simple 3-column layout, but what I want to achieve is this:

[image: Panels custom layout]

I did take a look at [Panels Extra Layouts](http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_layouts), but I'm not sure if that would cater for this.

EDIT: to clarify, I don't have a problem creating a layout like this with straight up HTML and CSS. I'm just looking for a way of introducing another region above the first two columns of a 3 column layout - something which the flexible layout editor doesn't seem to allow. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take a peek at the current layouts you have, and you can probably figure out how to add new regions, it's fairly straightforward.

There's also a tutorial here: http://drupal.org/node/495654

Comment: OK, I revisited the layout designer and was able to do what I wanted afterall. I must have overlooked the columns or something - it works perfectly, apart from a PHP error (but that's an entirely different issue obviously). Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out, and that you picked my answer as the right one, but that is not at all what I suggested ;)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but the tutorial turned out not to be necessary. "...you can probably figure out how to add new regions..." pretty much turned out to be the solution. Blame it on my impatience for not looking into it further initially :)

Comment: Maybe I should start replying that to everyone "You can figure it out" ;)

Comment: Well, I'll unmark this as the accepted answer if you feel that's appropriate. Despite my poor efforts to find the solution before coming here, this _is_ essentially the correct answer, so I marked it as such (and it did prompt me to dig further into the layout designer). If you simply said "You can figure it out" by itself then I probably wouldn't have accepted it :P

Comment: No no, I was only joking, it's just fine this way. :) If something does bother me it's people that never actually pick a solution when given good ones. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Drupal or Panels issue, but this has been a long standing issue with using divs and CSS instead of tables for layouts. Essentially unless you use Javascript, you can't really force divs stretch vertically and match the neighbor divs height. However there's a neat little trick featured on an article on "A List Apart" called "Faux Columns". It's quite old but I believe solves your problem. http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I actually have that part nailed already. I'm floating the first two columns left and using a combination of left margin and 100% height on the right column to achieve the height. Basically all I want to know is how I can introduce another region above the first two columns, as shown in my crudely photostopped image. I should have been clearer on that, sorry - I've changed the title to  better reflect the question.